# How to use QT libraries in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

I've currently got a project going in VS2008, but I want to use a couple of QT libraries. I've been told that If I install QT, I can configure it to compile using the VS2008 compiler, and so just transfer my work so far over, and be able to use the QT library as well. Is this the best solution, or can I install the QT Visual Studio plug-in, and use QT libraries through that?

(The libraries I want to use don't come with the basic QT package, and need to be downloaded and installed separately). e.g. http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- if standard compilation options fit with your needs, take the sdk
- otherwise, compile it : using a reasonably modern computer, compiling Qt 4.7.1 with QtWebkit (that you most probably don't need) takes around 100 minutes

Note that

- installing Visual Addon won't prevent you from installing the sdk : the addon is just here to helps with debugging / UI edition
- your project will have to be generated by either CMake or qmake so that your files are `moc`ed correctly (preprocessing of header files)
- anyway, you'll have to compile qwt yourself

My personalize advice: go for compilation and if it's the first time, compile the examples as well are they are more than useful to begin with.

Comment: I would certainly go for the sdk, no need to recompile something given to  you in official binary form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I neglected to mention that I'm using a library built to work in VS already in my project. Can I just include this in the .pro file, or will compiling it using the default MinGW cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also, Qt libraries are not working with standard mfc apps without some wrappers. if you want to use qt widgets in your source, you need to install qtwinmigrate, which could be found here http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qt-vs-addin](http://get.qt.nokia.com/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.7.exe), and configure libraries in qt->Qt Project Settings